# Email confirmation class view

Tags: django

I'm currently trying to display a confirmation html page when a user clicks the link in their email.  The URL I send in the email is `http://localhost:8000/confirm/?email=hello@example.com&conf_num=639836786717`

My class view for this, in order to validate if it's the right conf_number and email is as such

```
class ConfirmView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'confirm.html'
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        context = super(ConfirmView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        email = request.GET['email']
        sub = Newsletter.objects.get(email=email)
        if sub.conf_num == request.GET['conf_num']:
            sub.confirmed = True
            sub.save()
            action = "added"
        else:
            action = 'denied'
        context["email"] = email
        context['action'] = action
        return context
```

but I get this error `AttributeError: 'ConfirmView' object has no attribute 'object'`  on this line `context = super(ConfirmView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)` now I'm unsure that's because I'm calling Super on my custom class view?

Basically I want the confirmation email if it matches what we have in the Newsletter object to send to the template action added and denied if it doesn't match.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not defined **get_queryset method**, **get_object method**, or **model attribute**
according to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview)

Comment: there is no need to define all these, they are inherited by the parent class(es)

Comment: sorry, you were right, I missed there was no model attribute defined so yes, one of these should be defined

Answer (score 0):

The `get` method should return: `return self.render_to_response(context)`

Edit: As mentioned in Mugoma's reply, you should define one of those. You can inspect all of the methods available here:
https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/

Edit 2: Also, it seems to me that this should not be a DetailView. A DetailView typically used to display an instance of a given model, where:

> While this view is executing, self.object will contain the object that the view is operating upon.

In your case, some base view should suffice e.g. [TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview)